# how to add a column in an existing table?

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble adding a column to an existent .csv table using R.

For example, I have a table named **'Client'** with:

```
**ID | Genre | Name | Local |**
```

and I want to have something like this:

```
**ID | Genre | Name | Local | Occupation**
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use either of these methods:

1. `cbind(Client, Occupation)`
2. `colnames(Client) <- c("ID","Genre","Name","Local", "Occupation")`
3. `Client["Occupation"] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Client <- cbind(Client, Ocupation)
```

where `Ocupation` has the same length as the number of rows of `Client`.

Comment: It game me the following error: Error in cbind(Client, Ocupation) : 
  object 'Ocupation' not found. :(

Comment: Meanwhile, i used the following comand:  espetadores$ID_espetadores_PK<-NA, and it worked pretty fine for me! Thanks for the help, btw :)

Comment: `Ocupation` has to be defined as a vector with the elements corresponding to those you want to add in the `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use :

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, Ocupation = NA)
```